# Can I cancel my stateFlow respective collection using the stateFlow instance itself?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-stateflow

I can launch my stateFlow collection as below

```
val collectingScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
val stateFlow = MutableStateFlow(0)

val myJob =  collectingScope.launch {
        stateFlow.collect {
            println("collected $it")
        }
    }
```

And I can cancel it using

```
myJob.cancel()
```

But I wonder if I can also cancel it through the `stateFlow` instead?
I see there's a `cancel()` function but it's deprecated

```
@Deprecated(
    message = "cancel() is resolved into the extension of outer CoroutineScope which is likely to be an error." +
        "Use currentCoroutineContext().cancel() instead or specify the receiver of cancel() explicitly",
    level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR,
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith("currentCoroutineContext().cancel(cause)")
)
public fun FlowCollector<*>.cancel(cause: CancellationException? = null): Unit = noImpl()
```

If I can do so, does the cancelation also auto-cancel `myJob`?

Answer (score -1):

No.  StateFlows cannot be cancelled.  See the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/):

> State flow never completes. A call to Flow.collect on a state flow never completes normally, and neither does a coroutine started by the Flow.launchIn function. An active collector of a state flow is called a subscriber.